# Compute the integral in spherical coordinates system

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

Compute the following integral in spherical coordinates system:

- $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}-y^{2}}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\right)dzdxdy$$

---

I think the first triple integral is a sphere in the first octant, so the integral is equivalent to :
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\rho^{2}\sin\varphi\frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho\cos\varphi}}d\rho d\theta d\varphi=1.2566370\color{red}{4825}$$

But $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}-y^{2}}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\right)dzdxdy=1.2566370\color{red}{5686}$$

So why the answers are not the same?

Comment: What are you using to calculate in the first case? seems like a computation error

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/

Comment: I just tried it on wolfram and it gave me a third answer with different last digits - seems like some sort of rounding error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the first integral, the value is $\frac{2\pi}5$, both when you use Cartesian coordinates and spherical coordinates. So, that difference that you get is just due to a rounding error.